# What is a lever in physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, terminology, torque

Sorry if my question seems naive but I am just beginning to learn rotational motion and I am very confused about the concept of [lever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever). What is it? Can it is be of any shape, like long cirular etc. And most importantly what I am confused about is,when u are trying to rotate a non point particle object, is what’s called a “lever” a part of that object, like the distance from axis of rotation to edge.Or is lever always a external object like axle turing the wheel. So from this, what is the lever of a small screw?

Comment: Isn't this something you could easily look up on the internet or in your textbook?

Comment: When used for the intended purpose of inserting or removing screws, a screwdriver is usually classified as a *wheel and axle* device, rather than a *lever*. See http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/explain-how-screw-driver-could-used-lever-wheel-112993.

Comment: No. It's not something i can easily look up in internet. Maybe I am mixing up my vocabularies, but the reason I am asking about lever, is that sometimes when rotating a circular object like wheel, I see it being rotated by hand on edge  (where distance between axis of rotation to edge is called lever) and sometimes by like a tool like bicycle pedal or wrench (also called lever), which seems to intersect the axis of rotation and technically should not rotate the wheel at all? So that's why I am asking what is a lever so I can get my basic's right!

Answer (score 2):

> Or is lever always a external object like axle turing the wheel. So from this, what is the lever of a small screw?

There are four elements involved in a lever, a rigid rod, an end that can applied to an object,  a fulcrum, and a mechanical advantage to be gained by using it.

[image]

A fairly obvious (I hope) lever for removing car wheels.

Initially I would have said a screwdriver was not a lever, unless you use it to prise something like the lid of a jar, that is open it from the side. I would think it's obvious it is a lever used in that way.

But if you think of the sharp flat blade that fits into the screw head, as a wedge, and then consider the handle of the screwdriver as giving you increased torque, then I guess it could be called a lever.

In this case the leverage action comes from the mechanical advantage of the larger diameter of the handle, since it is a good bit wider than the thing you are trying to turn, that is the screw. The shaft of the screwdriver provides a fulcrum for the handle to revolve.

[image]

A non-obvious (to me anyway) lever for removing flat headed slotted screws.

Answer (score 0):

The lever is just whatever combines the force with the object. I'm sure there is some accurate English definition of the word "lever".

If I pull in a wrench, my force is causing a torque on the screw, **because** there is a connection from force to object. This connection is the wrench arm; that would be my lever in this case. It doesn't matter what and which shape. It just has to be rigid (otherwise my force would *not* be able to cause the torque I wanted).

Often when you hear the terms **lever** and **lever arm**, people actually just mean the *distance* from where the force is applied to the rotation centre. There doesn't even have to be anything in between - the lever itself could be a weird circular shape - the only thing that matters, is the perpendicular *distance*. Because that's what you need to calculate the torque.

Answer (score 0):

When used for the intended purpose of inserting or removing screws, a screwdriver is usually classified as a *wheel and axle* device, rather than a *lever*. See http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/explain-how-screw-driver-could-used-lever-wheel-112993.

The differences are that in the wheel and axle there is no fulcrum, and instead of *forces* the effort and load are now *torques*.

[image]